# How to serialize Exception object using Kyro?

Tags: java, serialization, kryo

I have following custom exception which i need to serialize using kryo library.

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {
 public CustomException(){}
}
```

This is my seralizer

```
Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
kryo.writeClassAndObject(out, obj);
```

But serialization throws following exception.

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor):    java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList
Serialization trace:
suppressedExceptions (CustomException)
at      com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo$DefaultInstantiatorStrategy.newInstantiatorOf(      Kryo.java:1272)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newInstantiator(Kryo.java:1078)
```

I have resolved this registering the `CustomException` with `JavaSerializer`

```
 kryo.register(CustomException.class, new JavaSerializer());
```

But since `JavaSerializer` is very inefficient ( advised avoid using if possible in   JavaSerializer javadoc) is there other way to serialize Exception object in kryo ?

Comment: You've already have an exception thrown which is more inefficient than Java serializer. Unless your application throws a lot of exceptions frequently I don't see the point trying to customize this.

Comment: I face the same problem... How did you solve this?

Comment: Use `JavaSerializer` as I have stated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation, this can be fixed in several ways:

> Serializers for a specific type use Java code to create a new instance
>   of that type. Serializers such as FieldSerializer are generic and must
>   handle creating a new instance of any class. By default, if a class
>   has a zero argument constructor then it is invoked via ReflectASM or
>   reflection, otherwise an exception is thrown. If the zero argument
>   constructor is private, an attempt is made to access it via reflection
>   using setAccessible. If this is acceptable, a private zero argument
>   constructor is a good way to allow Kryo to create instances of a class
>   without affecting the public API.
>
> When ReflectASM or reflection cannot be used, Kryo can be configured
>   to use an InstantiatorStrategy to handle creating instances of a
>   class. Objenesis provides StdInstantiatorStrategy which uses JVM
>   specific APIs to create an instance of a class without calling any
>   constructor at all. While this works on many JVMs, a zero argument is
>   generally more portable.
>
> ```
> kryo.setInstantiatorStrategy(new StdInstantiatorStrategy()); Note that classes must be designed to be created in this way. If a class
> ```
>
> expects its constructor to be called, it may be in an uninitialized
>   state when created through this mechanism.
>
> In many situations, you may want to have a strategy, where Kryo first
>   tries to find and use a no-arg constructor and if it fails to do so,
>   it should try to use StdInstantiatorStrategy as a fallback, because
>   this one does not invoke any constructor at all. The configuration for
>   this behavior could be expressed like this:
>
> kryo.setInstantiatorStrategy(new Kryo.DefaultInstantiatorStrategy(new
>   StdInstantiatorStrategy())); However, the default behavior is to
>   require a no-arg constructor.
>
> Objenesis can also create new objects using Java's built-in
>   serialization mechanism. Using this, the class must implement
>   java.io.Serializable and the first zero argument constructor in a
>   super class is invoked.
>
> ```
> kryo.setInstantiatorStrategy(new SerializingInstantiatorStrategy()); You may also write your own
> ```
>
> InstantiatorStrategy.
>
> To customize only how a specific type is created, an
>   ObjectInstantiator can be set. This will override ReflectASM,
>   reflection, and the InstantiatorStrategy.
>
> ```
> Registration registration = kryo.register(SomeClass.class);
> registration.setObjectInstantiator(...); Alternatively, some serializers provide methods that can be overridden to customize object
> ```
>
> creation.
>
> ```
> kryo.register(SomeClass.class, new FieldSerializer(kryo, SomeClass.class) {
>    public Object create (Kryo kryo, Input input, Class type) {
>       return new SomeClass("some constructor arguments", 1234);
>    }
> });
> ```

Example:

```
/**
 * Because the creation/initialization of Kryo instances is rather expensive, 
 * in a multithreaded scenario you should pool Kryo instances. A very simple solution 
 * is to bind Kryo instances to Threads using ThreadLocal, like this:
 */
private static final ThreadLocal<Kryo> kryoThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Kryo>() {
    @Override
    protected Kryo initialValue() {
        Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
        /*
         * In many situations, you may want to have a strategy, where Kryo first tries to find and use a no-arg constructor 
         * and if it fails to do so, it should try to use StdInstantiatorStrategy as a fallback, because this one does 
         * not invoke any constructor at all. The configuration for this behavior could be expressed like this:
         */
        kryo.setInstantiatorStrategy(new Kryo.DefaultInstantiatorStrategy(new StdInstantiatorStrategy()));
        return kryo;
    }
};
```